# What is causing this invalid syntax error in my Python script?

Tags: python

Why is the 'else' part marked in red when I try to run it? It says 'invalid syntax'.

```
def interseccion(lista, lista2, resultado=[]):
if lista != []:
    if lista[0] in lista2:
        return interseccion(lista[1:], lista2, resultado+[lista[0]]
    else:                 
        return interseccion(lista[1:], lista2, resultado]

return resultado
```

Comment: Your opening parenthesis - '(' has no closing parenthesis ')'... maybe other problems too.

Comment: [Mutable default arguments can cause troubles.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

Comment: Aside: the idea of the question title is to summarize the question in a way which will be useful to other people who might be looking to help or looking for an answer to the same question.  "Why I'm getting this error? Im a noobie" isn't very likely to be.

Answer (score 2):

The specific error is due to a missing close parenthesis:

```
    return interseccion(lista[1:], lista2, resultado+[lista[0]] ) <-- that parenthesis is needed
```

Comment: And similarly in the second call to `interseccion()` (or, I suppose I should write `interseccion(`) — though there's a difference; there's a stray `]` there in lieu of the `)`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you are correct, but the question specifically asked about the error surrounding the `else`.

Comment: @user2833752 in general, when you have a syntax error, you should look before the identified part to find the issue

Answer (score 0):

You have to close your parentheses in both of your return statements:

```
return interseccion(lista[1:], lista2, resultado+[lista[0]])
```

and

```
return interseccion(lista[1:], lista2, resultado)
```

Also `if lista != []:` is more idiomatically written simply as `if lista:`.

And I'm not quite sure if you want `resultado` to be an empty list by default! Maybe the default value should be `None` instead and then you can specify:

```
if resultado is None:
    resultado = []
```

at the beginning.